# How can I get an ImageView to fill parent on a relative layout?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, fill-parent

I am attempting to stretch a 300x300 image to fill the parent as a background for a sample layout. However, it seems that at most it can reach it's max dimensions as a perfect square. Here is my code.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/app_background"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

There is still white space at both the top and bottom of the app and I want to eliminate that. Any and all solutions to this dilemma would be greatly appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTlSZ.png)

Comment: why not setting parent's `android:background` to `@drawable/app_background`? **EDIT**: as @Chisko suggested you can also use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your `ImageView`

Comment: play around with `android:scaleType`, the `fitCenter` current option is the responsible of the "perfect sqaure" thing

Comment: OMG thank you Stefan Golubovic! I would have never known about this Without your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use **match_parent**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/app_background"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: `fill_parent` is the same as `match_parent`.

Comment: When I tried using that it didn't work, but I found another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="org.jtb.stretchtest.MainActivity">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/test"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the parent element has paddings.

Set Android padding of the parent widget to **0dp** Eg:
`android:padding = "0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/app_background"/>
```